# Association control - access denied

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm using Alfresco Share 4.2c and association.ftl to display associations and to allow objects in the repository to be picked. I run into problem to display metadata for user who doesn't have permission to see associated object.
I got an error:

***Template processing error: 
"get(properties) failed on instance of            org.alfresco.repo.template.TemplateNode" get(properties) failed on instance of org.alfresco.repo.template.TemplateNode.
The problematic instruction:----------
==> ${row.item.properties.name!""} escaped ${jsonUtils.encodeJSONString(row.item.properties.name!"")} [on line 36, column 42 in org/alfresco/repository/forms/pickerresults.lib.ftl]
 in user-directive pickerResultsLib.pickerResultsJSON [on line 2, column 1 in org/alfresco/repository/forms/pickeritems.post.json.ftl]***

and AccessDeniedException.

Any help or advice for this problem is appreciated.
I would also like to have a label on the document details page with text "Access denied". 
Maybe I have to create my custom association.ftl? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: For association related control you could configure it in share-config-custom.xml. what are the steps you have followed for this?

Comment: In share-config-custom.xml I have `<control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/association.ftl" >  <control-param name="displayMode">items</control-param>  <control-param name="showTargetLink">true</control-param>  </control>` and it works fine for users who have permissions to access related document, on document details page there is a link to that document. In case that user doesn't have that permission I get the error and on the document details page there is no item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy **/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/forms/pickerresults.lib.ftl** to the extension folder and change the following loop

```
<#list results as row>
            {
                "type": "${row.item.typeShort}",
                "parentType": "${row.item.parentTypeShort!""}",
                "isContainer": ${row.item.isContainer?string},
                "name": "${row.item.properties.name!""}",
                "title": "${row.item.properties.title!""}",
                "description": "${row.item.properties.description!""}",
                <#if row.item.properties.modified??>"modified": "${xmldate(row.item.properties.modified)}",</#if>
                <#if row.item.properties.modifier??>"modifier": "${row.item.properties.modifier}",</#if>
                <#if row.item.siteShortName??>"site": "${row.item.siteShortName}",</#if>
                "displayPath": "${row.item.displayPath!""}",
                "nodeRef": "${row.item.nodeRef}"<#if row.selectable?exists>,
                "selectable" : ${row.selectable?string}</#if>
            }<#if row_has_next>,</#if>
        </#list>
```

Encapsulate the inside with an extra **if row.item.hasPermission("Read")**
Something like this:

```
    <#list results as row>
        <#if row.item.hasPermission("Read")>
                {
                    "type": "${row.item.typeShort}",
                    "parentType": "${row.item.parentTypeShort!""}",
                    "isContainer": ${row.item.isContainer?string},
                    "name": "${row.item.properties.name!""}",
                    "title": "${row.item.properties.title!""}",
                    "description": "${row.item.properties.description!""}",
                    <#if row.item.properties.modified??>"modified": "${xmldate(row.item.properties.modified)}",</#if>
                    <#if row.item.properties.modifier??>"modifier": "${row.item.properties.modifier}",</#if>
                    <#if row.item.siteShortName??>"site": "${row.item.siteShortName}",</#if>
                    "displayPath": "${row.item.displayPath!""}",
                    "nodeRef": "${row.item.nodeRef}"<#if row.selectable?exists>,
                    "selectable" : ${row.selectable?string}</#if>
                }<#if row_has_next>,</#if>
            </#if>
</#list>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, there is no error about permissions anymore. Also I have to create custom association.ftl because I would like to display a label with text "Access denied". I want my user to know that association exists, but he doesn't have permission to see that object. Thanks again, you've helped me a lot!